# vim - delete everything between tab characters

Tags: vim

I have a file that has tab separated data.  I need to delete 2 columns.  So, what command(s) can I use to delete everything from the current tab to the next tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete columns 4 and 5:

```
:%s/^\(.\{-}\t\)\{3}\zs.\{-}\t.\{-}\t//
```

Explanation:

```
^  => start of line

.\{−} => as few characters as possible
\( .\{-}\t \)\{3} => three times as few characters as possible followed with a tab

\zs => start of match
```

It could be clearer with the `\v` switch:

```
:%s/\v^(.{-}\t){3}\zs.{-}\t.{-}\t//
```

Answer (score 3):

I think shift+ctrl+v is what you are looking for.

http://jvi.sourceforge.net/javahelpset/jvi-vis_block.html

Answer (score 2):

Does this have to be done in vim?  If you have a unix command line I'd go instead for the good old `cut` command. For example the following will keep the first column, and everything including & after the 4th (discards 2 & 3)

```
cat filename | cut -d"\t" -f1,4- > outputfile
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, although in my case, I'm only changing some of the lines, so it won't work.

Comment: @David Oneil: You can pipe a selected set of lines to an exterior command.  For example `:4,10!cut -d"\t" -f1,4-` will pipe only lines 4 through 10 through the cut command.

Comment: @rampion: is there a way to say "starting on line 10 to the end"?

Comment: @David Oneil `:10,$!cut -d"\t" -f1,4-` will give you lines 10 to the end (`$`)

Answer (score 2):

While you can use regular expressions, it is better to use simple `f` or `t` normal commands: when you are at the first character of the first column you want to delete `d2f<Tab>` will delete this and next columns unless one column can include newline in it. If it can, then `d2/<Tab>/e<CR>` (or `d2/\t/e<CR>`) will do what you want. To expand it on other lines, use macros: `qaqqa01f<Tab>d2t<Tab>j@aq@a`:

1. `qaq`: clear `a` register (starts recording a macros that will be stored in `a` register and then immediately stops recording before typing anything else);
2. `qa`: start recording a macros in register `a`;
3. `0`: go to the very beginning of the line;
4. `1f<Tab>`: jump to next tab. `1` may be omitted here. If you want to delete first column, then omit the whole motion;
5. `d2t<Tab>`: delete to second next tab;
6. `j`: move to next line;
7. `@a`: run macros stored in register `a`. It is empty at this point (because it was cleared in 1st item), so nothing is actually done;
8. `q`: stop recording a macros;
9. `@a`: run macros stored in register `a`. It contains items 3.-7. and in 7th item it will run itself.

Comment: Yay macros are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s:\t[^\t]\+\t:\t\t:
```

This deletes everything between two tabs.

HTH

Comment: Am i correct in assuming that this leaves behind the tabs on both sides of the column?

Comment: Yes because the question asked: delete everything from the current tab to the next tab.